# No road movement on JavaScript car race game

Tags: javascript, loops

I found a tutorial for programming a car race game in JavaScript, my progress is ok overall, but I got stuck when it comes to giving the road movement, it was done with a loop that repeats small blocks of the road.

I tried to do it my way and also follow the video instructions, as well as changing some of the values (which shouldn't affect it, because the changes were mainly the height/width of the road etc.)

My main issue is that whenever I click the Start Game button, it shows the road all at once, I can't see any movement on the road loop, yet, I can see activity on the console, such as many div elements created consecutively, just as it should be supposed to, but still no visual difference on the road.

I leave a link to my repository ( https://github.com/CatVirus22/car-racer-game/tree/main/src ) where all the code is located, attempted to deploy the site on Netlify and for

```js
const speedDash = document.querySelector(".speedDash");
const scoreDash = document.querySelector(".scoreDash");
const lifeDash = document.querySelector(".lifeDash");
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const startBtn = document.querySelector(".startBtn");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame);
document.addEventListener("keydown", pressKeyOn);
document.addEventListener("keyup", pressKeyOff);

let animation;
let gamePlay = false;
let player;
let keys = {
  ArrowUp: false,
  ArrowDown: false,
  ArrowLeft: false,
  ArrowRight: false,
};

function startGame(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(gamePlay);
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "playerCar");
  div.x = 425;
  div.y = 500;
  container.appendChild(div);
  gamePlay = true;
  animation = requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
  player = {
    ele: div,
    speed: 1,
    lives: 3,
    score: 0,
    enemyCars: 15,
    roadwidth: 350,
  };
  startBoard();
}

function disableBtn(btn) {
  btn.disabled = true;
}

function startBoard() {
  for (let x = 0; x < 14; x++) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "road");
    div.style.top = x * 100 + "px";
    div.style.width = player.roadwidth + "px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#444";
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function pressKeyOn(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(keys);
  keys[event.key] = true;
}

function pressKeyOff(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(keys);
  keys[event.key] = false;
}

function updateDash() {
  //console.log(player);
  scoreDash.innerHTML = Math.round(player.score);
  lifeDash.innerHTML = player.lives;
  speedDash.innerHTML = Math.round(player.speed * 14);
}

function moveRoad() {
  let tempRoad = document.querySelectorAll(".road");
  console.log(tempRoad);
  let prevRoad = tempRoad[0].offsetLeft;
  for (let x = 0; x < tempRoad.lenght; x++) {
    let num = tempRoad[x].offsetTop + player.speed;
    if (num > 600) {
    }
    tempRoad[x].style.top = num + "px";
  }
}

function playGame() {
  if (gamePlay) {
    updateDash();
    moveRoad();
    ///movementcar
    if (keys.ArrowUp) {
      if (player.ele.y > 100) player.ele.y -= 1;
      player.speed = player.speed < 20 ? player.speed + 0.07 : 20;
    }
    if (keys.ArrowDown) {
      if (player.ele.y < 600) player.ele.y += 1;
      player.speed = player.speed > 0 ? player.speed - 0.2 : 0;
    }
    if (keys.ArrowRight) {
      player.ele.x += player.speed;
    }
    if (keys.ArrowLeft) {
      player.ele.x -= player.speed;
    }
    ///movecar

    player.ele.style.top = player.ele.y + "px";
    player.ele.style.left = player.ele.x + "px";
  }
  const animation = requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: salmon;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.startBtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 185px;
  height: 50px;
  color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid rgb(43, 42, 42);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 83, 83);
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background-color ease-out 100ms;
  display: grid;
}

.startBtn:hover {
  background-color: #ca1c1c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dashboard {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 750px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #076d1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.road {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.road:before {
  content: "|";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  line-height: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.playerCar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 425px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url(../images/player-car.png);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Race Car Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles_racer_car.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Car Racer </h1>

    <div class="dashboard">
      <span class="speedDash"></span><span class="input">/Mph</span>
      <span class="input">| Score: </span><span class="scoreDash"></span>
      <span class="input">| Lives: </span><span class="lifeDash"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input
      type="button"
      class="startBtn"
      value="Start game"
      onclick="disableBtn(this)"
    />

    <script src="src/index_racer_car.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

some reason it is just not working

Comment: In the `moveRoad` function, you have an empty if statement. Is that corect? What should that function do? And could you explain what function is supposed to render your road? And what logic allows it move? We haven't followed this tutorial, so we'll need you're guidance to be able to help you out.

Comment: The StartBoard function is the one in charge to display the .road div which was created inside this function, it is called with the querySelectorAll into the moveRoad function, the logic is to move every 50px block downwards and create new blocks on top of the container so that it gives the movement sensation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the tutorial is teaching you or what the result should be, but I would solve it with CSS. The reason for this is that JavaScript isn't generally good in animating elements based on `requestAnimationFrame` and changing the values of the `top`, `left`, or other directions. (Unless you're using the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API)).

With [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) you could look a *sprite-like* element with a repeated pattern that resembles a road - like the background in `.road::after` element in the snippet below - and loop an animation, creating the illusion of speeding over a road. Speed is controlled here with seconds, as in how many seconds does the complete animation take.
It might take some math, but it will give you fine-grained control over how fast a single element moves.

```js
const speedDash = document.querySelector(".speedDash");
const scoreDash = document.querySelector(".scoreDash");
const lifeDash = document.querySelector(".lifeDash");
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const startBtn = document.querySelector(".startBtn");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame);
document.addEventListener("keydown", pressKeyOn);
document.addEventListener("keyup", pressKeyOff);

let animation;
let gamePlay = false;
let player;
let road;
let keys = {
  ArrowUp: false,
  ArrowDown: false,
  ArrowLeft: false,
  ArrowRight: false,
};

function startGame(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(gamePlay);
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "playerCar");
  div.x = 425;
  div.y = 500;
  container.appendChild(div);
  gamePlay = true;
  animation = requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
  player = {
    ele: div,
    speed: 1,
    lives: 3,
    score: 0,
    enemyCars: 15,
    roadwidth: 350,
  };
  startBoard();
}

function disableBtn(btn) {
  btn.disabled = true;
}

function startBoard() {
  road = document.createElement('div');
  road.classList.add('road');
  container.appendChild(road);
}

function pressKeyOn(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(keys);
  keys[event.key] = true;
}

function pressKeyOff(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(keys);
  keys[event.key] = false;
}

function updateDash() {
  //console.log(player);
  scoreDash.innerHTML = Math.round(player.score);
  lifeDash.innerHTML = player.lives;
  speedDash.innerHTML = Math.round(player.speed * 14);
}

function playGame() {
  if (gamePlay) {
    updateDash();
    ///movementcar
    if (keys.ArrowUp) {
      if (player.ele.y > 100) player.ele.y -= 1;
      player.speed = player.speed < 20 ? player.speed + 0.07 : 20;
    }
    if (keys.ArrowDown) {
      if (player.ele.y < 600) player.ele.y += 1;
      player.speed = player.speed > 0 ? player.speed - 0.2 : 0;
    }
    if (keys.ArrowRight) {
      player.ele.x += player.speed;
    }
    if (keys.ArrowLeft) {
      player.ele.x -= player.speed;
    }
    ///movecar

    player.ele.style.top = player.ele.y + "px";
    player.ele.style.left = player.ele.x + "px";
  }
  const animation = requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: salmon;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.startBtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 185px;
  height: 50px;
  color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid rgb(43, 42, 42);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 83, 83);
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background-color ease-out 100ms;
  display: grid;
}

.startBtn:hover {
  background-color: #ca1c1c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dashboard {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 750px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #076d1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@keyframes drive {
  from {
    translate: 0 -50%;
  }
  
  to {
    translate: 0 0%;
  }
}

.road {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #444;
  animation: drive 1s 0s linear infinite;
}

.road::before {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0, white 0%, white 20%, #444 20%, #444 100%);
  background-size: auto;
  background-size: 100% 25%;
}



.playerCar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 425px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url(../images/player-car.png);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Race Car Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles_racer_car.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Car Racer </h1>

    <div class="dashboard">
      <span class="speedDash"></span><span class="input">/Mph</span>
      <span class="input">| Score: </span><span class="scoreDash"></span>
      <span class="input">| Lives: </span><span class="lifeDash"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input
      type="button"
      class="startBtn"
      value="Start game"
      onclick="disableBtn(this)"
    />

    <script src="src/index_racer_car.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will try to do that and find the right values to make it move, this was a simple tutorial so they decided to use the `requestAnimationFrame`, this was with the idea of making a loop on this small `50px` blocks, and make them give the impression the road is being left behind as the block are moving downwards.

will try with `CSS Animations` and see how it goes